# Does $H\vDash AC$

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, axiom-of-choice

The set $H_\kappa$ of sets hereditarily of cardinality less than $\kappa$ is defined as $H_\kappa=\{x||tc(x)|\lt\kappa\}$. What if we define the set $H=H_{Ord}$ of sets hereditarily of cardinality less than $Ord$; $H$ is the class of sets with some ordinal number as there cardinality. Equivalently, $H$ is the class of hereditarily well-ordered sets.

It is immediately obvious $V=H$ is equivalent to $AC$. My questions are as follows:

1. Is it true that $ZF\vdash H\vDash ZF$? Is it true that $ZF\vdash H\vDash ZFC$?
2. More generally, does $ZF\vdash H_\kappa\vDash AC$?
3. What is the consistency strength of the existence of some $j: H\prec H$? Is the existence of such an embedding first order expressible?

(I am obviously working in the context of $ZF$ without choice. I define $|tc(x)|\lt\kappa\leftrightarrow\exists\lambda\lt\kappa(|tc(x)|=\lambda)$)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, yes, and not sure.

$H$ (and $H_\kappa$ in general) always satisfies choice, because any family of nonempty sets in $H$ has a well orderable transitive closure, from whence we can define a choice function, which is easily hereditarily well orderable as well.

However, $H\models\sf Power$ if and only if choice holds on $V$. Otherwise, let $\alpha$ be the least ordinal with a power set that cannot be well ordered, then $\mathcal P(\alpha)\subseteq H$ but it is not an element of $H$.

Comment: Do you have an idea on the consistency strength of some $j: H\prec H$?

Comment: No, but I'd hazard a guess that it's very high.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will wait a little while to see if anyone has the answer to part 3 before accepting.

Comment: $HOD$ seems to be a subclass of $H$, but do you know if it is actually definable in $H$?

Comment: @Yair: I was debating exactly that a few minutes ago. It's not immediately clear to me one way or another.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning replacement can fail in $H_{\kappa}.$ For example, in the Feferman-Levy extension of $L,$ $H_{\omega_1}$ fails replacement since the $\omega_n^L$'s are definable in $H_{\omega_1}.$

Comment: Even if it is determined $HOD$ is definable in $H$, what is the consistency strength of the existence of some $j: HOD\prec HOD$?

Comment: @Master: If my memory serves me right, it would contradict to HOD Conjecture. So, what *is* the consistency of such an embedding? Very high.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, what will happen if we take class length of production lottery sums with add a Cohen subset and add a choiceless Cohen subset with respect to stage 
$\kappa$. I want to force over V and make the H in the symmetric extension omit the definition of HOD

Comment: @AsagKaragila So presumably, $ZFC+I0$ is less than $ZF+j: HOD\prec HOD$, which is less than or equal $ZFC+j: HOD\prec HOD$, which is less than $ZF+j: V\prec V$?

Comment: @Master: Presumably.